# Typescript , How to infer type from another property value?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have an interface with properties: `key` and `value`, I want to infer value type by the key.

```js
interface Obj { a: number; b: string }

interface Param<K extends keyof Obj> {
  key: K
  value: Obj[K] // I want to infer this type
}

const p: Param<keyof Obj> = {
  key: 'a',
  value: '', // typescript can't infer this type, expect number
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

`Obj[K]` means a value that can be gotten by indexing `Obj` by any of the values in `K`, not just the one `key` is.

So, to use this structure, you need to specify which key is used more closely:

```
interface Obj { a: number; b: string }

interface Param<K extends keyof Obj> {
  key: K
  value: Obj[K]
}

const p: Param<'a'> = { // changed line
  key: 'a',
  value: '', // error
}
```

There's no way to infer the generic parameter, sadly.

---

If you already know what's in `Obj`, there may be a better way to do this.

```
interface AParam {
    key: 'a'
    value: number
}

interface BParam {
    key: 'b'
    value: string
}

type Param = AParam | BParam;

const p: Param = {
  key: 'a',
  value: '', // error
}
```

This is the only approach that will work if you need the variable `p` to be able to hold either `key`, but still have the `value` be the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

You can reach this goal with the help of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

```
type ParamHelper<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { key: K; value: T[K] } };
type Param<T> = ParamHelper<T>[keyof ParamHelper<T>];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type param<o> = {
    [k in keyof o]: {
        key: k,
        value: o[k]
    }
}[keyof o];
const o = {a:1, b:2} as const
const a: param<typeof o> ={
    key:'a',
    value:1
}
```